# Show that $E[X] \leqslant m-1+nP[X \geq m]$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, random-variables

Show that for every discrete random variable X taking values in the set {1,...,n} and for every m $\in$ {1,....,n} we have:

$$
E[X] \leqslant m-1+nP[X \geq m]
$$

What I know by definition is that:
$$
E[X] 
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& = \sum^n_{k=0} k * P(X=k) \\
& = \sum^{m-1}_{k=0} k * P(X=k) + \sum^n_{k=m} k * P(X=k) 
\end{aligned}
$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $\sum^{m-1}_{k=0} k * P(X=k) + \sum^n_{k=0} k * P(X=k) \le \sum^{m-1}_{k=0} (m - 1) * P(X=k) + \sum^n_{k=0} n * P(X=k)$

Comment: I supposed that you changed both k's with the respective higher interval of the sum. Is that to bring outside the summation "m-1" and "n"?

Comment: The second sum should start at $m$, not $0$.

Comment: Fixed the typo, sorry.

Comment: Mostly my doubt is on how: $\sum^{m-1}_{k=0} P(X=k) + \sum^n_{k=m} P(X=k) = P(X \geq m)$

Comment: It is only the second sum that is equal to P(X≥m) ( just use that probabilities on disjoint events is additive). The first sum can trivially be estimated to be lower than 1.

Answer (score 1):

As you have shown before we have that

\begin{aligned}[t]
E[X] & = \sum^n_{k=1} k * P(X=k) \\
& = \sum^{m-1}_{k=1} k * P(X=k) + \sum^n_{k=m} k * P(X=k) \\
& \leq \sum^{m-1}_{k=1} (m-1) * P(X=k) + \sum^n_{k=m} n * P(X=k) \\
& = (m-1) * \sum^{m-1}_{k=1} P(X=k) +  n * \sum^n_{k=m}P(X=k) \\
& =(m-1) * P(X \leq m-1) +  n * P(X \geq m) \\
& \leq (m-1) +  n * P(X \geq m) \\
\end{aligned}

the last inequality comes from the fact that $P(X \leq m-1) \leq 1 $

Comment: The character $*$ is generally understood to be the convolution operator. Use $\cdot$ or nothing at all to indicate multiplication.

Comment: @Snoop I was using the same notation as OP